# Will pygobject for Python 3 be included in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, python, gtk, application-development, pygtk

Will pygobject of Python 3 be included with Ubuntu 11.10? I am interested in using the new features provided with GTK3 with Python 3 but I have been unable due to the complexity involved with getting pygobject setup with Python 3. And since Python 3.2 is included by default (that's what I've heard anyways), now would be the perfect time to include pygobject for it as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/pygobject) for pygobject shows that 3.0.0 is in Oneiric, and that there is a python3-gobject package available for it.